# can't install ubuntu it gets stuck on installing grub2

Tags: grub2, system-installation, usb-installation

I've been trying all day just to get linux working on my machine.
I downloaded an iso of ubuntu budgie and made it bootable with rufus on windows  and it literally hates me.
first off I had to use rufus not etcher because it would get stuck at a clonezilla screen.
now that I have used rufus it will boot but hates to work I have tried booting it twice to the installer and each time it gets stuck on "installing grub2" for hours. I read to give it time but I have given it 2 hours at one point so that's enough "time" in my opinion. Basically I haven't been able to do it. I have tried this three times. it never really spits out errors it just never moves on from installing grub2 and I have even tried using normal ubuntu 18.04 and it does the same thing getting stuck on installing grub2
can someone help me with where I went wrong? I just want my system up and running :(

- List item

Comment: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the summary report ( not post full report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair My full install to an SSD is about 10 minutes. But full install to a USB3 flash drive was over an hour.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a BIOS with UEFI capability, you need to create a GPT disk with a small EFI partition for the bootloader so the installer can "see" it.

I had a similar problem when adding an Intel Optane SSD to my older system and installing Kubuntu. My system is i4790K based motherboard that doesn't fully support NVME drives, but I used a PCIE based Optane and it works just fine using a SATA SSD to boot from the EFI partition, and run Kubuntu and Windows OS on the Optane drive.

I thought it was the BIOS blocking me at first but turns out it was the type of partitions I had - MBR vs GPT preventing me from creating an EFI area. If you're using UEFI BIOS you should use GPT and create a small EFI boot partition. Once I wiped the SSD and changed to GPT with the Live Kubuntu disk partitioning app (like Gpart), I was able to create an EFI boot partition (100MB is big enough for both Linux and Windows bootloaders) on my Samsung 860 SSD, plus a Windows 10 and Kubuntu storage partitions so I could dual-boot. Note that Windows will not install on MBR when set to UEFI in the BIOS, GPT partitions only. Once I realized this and changed all drives to GPT and add an EFI boot partition, the installer was able to locate where to put GRUB on my SSD and the install completed normally within a few minutes.

Note if you want to dual-boot Windows, you should create all the GPT partitions you want to use first, then install Windows so it's easier to get it placed where you want on the disk. Then install Ubuntu after so GRUB can find and configure the setup for both bootloaders.

Very happy with the results here.